# Java redundant code 4 times same stuff with different getter and setters

Tags: java

I would like to shorten my code a little bit. I've got 4 IFs which are doing the same stuff but need a different attribute from the object. A different get.
I loop through those ifs with loopElement.

```
if (!toCompareElement.getSomething().contains(loopElement.getSomething())) {
  // Some code with loopElement.getSomething()
}
if (!toCompareElement.getSomethingElse().contains(loopElement.getSomethingElse())) {
  // Some code with loopElement.getSomethingElse()
}
if (!toCompareElement.getSomethingDifferent().contains(loopElement.getSomethingDifferent())) {
  // Some code with loopElement.getSomethingDifferent()
}
if (!toCompareElement.getDifferentSomething().contains(loopElement.getDifferentSomething())) {
  // Some code with loopElement.getDifferentSomething()
}
```

Comment: Move `Some code` into a method or use `||` (OR) to merge the `if`s into a single one

Comment: But I need the same attribute in the code as I need in the if

Comment: "which are doing the same, but need a different attribute", this means they don't do the same. I don't really see a problem here

Comment: As mentioned move `some code` into a method which you call from inside the if.

Comment: It should look if the loopElement already exist in the toCompareElement. If it doesn't exist it should add it to the toCompareElement. The toCompareElement does have multiple attributes. Every if is one attribute.

Comment: Sounds like you should overwrite `hashCode` and  `equals` methods and simply call `!toComapreElement.equals(loopElement)` to check if the loop element should be added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function to generalise the logic of your if statements (although I'm not clear whether `toCompareElement` and `loopElement` have the same types, or whether the latter is a collection of the former:

```java
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;

interface Container {
    boolean contains(Container e);
}
interface Element {
    Container getSomething();
    Container getSomethingElse();
}
public class Operation {
    public static void elementOp(Function<Element,Container> extractor, Consumer<Element> operation, Element toCompare, Element loop) {
        if (!extractor.apply(toCompare).contains(extractor.apply(loop))) {
            operation.accept(loop);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Element toCompareElement = ...;
        Element loopElement = ...;
        elementOp(Element::getSomething, e -> {}, toCompareElement, loopElement);
        elementOp(Element::getSomethingElse, e -> {}, toCompareElement, loopElement);
    }
}
```

This is written assuming that all your `Element` methods return `Container` instances, and that one `Container` can contain another. You may need to change that type to something else. This part of your question is unclear.